# How to specify file path in mail body - Azure devops Send Email task

Tags: azure-devops, sendmail

In Jenkins, using Editable Email Notification, we specify Default Content as **${FILE,path="abc\SummaryReport.html"}**
In this way the HTML file will be shown in the body of the mail when received.

I am looking for syntax how we can specify in Azure Devops - Send Email task - Mail Body

[image]

Please suggest how to specify the file path in mail body of Send Email task in Azure Devops.

Comment: Hi @ram, how are things going? Have you tried the suggestion in my answer? Is it helpful to you? Please have a try with it. Any update, feel free to tell us.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that syntax should work, but you need a "get files" step that pulls that file from a repository to the working directory first.

Comment: I am able to access the working directory files, I mentioned "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\reports\latestReport\TestReport.html" in attachment &  able to get that file as attachment in the email I received. In the similar way, I am trying to show the Summary of my test(SummaryReport.html) in email body. 

For that I need the syntax in azure.
${FILE,path="abc\SummaryReport.html"} this didn't work in Azure.

I am getting
##[error]Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Body'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send the Mail Body as HTML Body (enable the option "**Is HTML Body?**"), and use the '**`a`**' tag to set a link to the HTML file. Here you need to write and format the whole mail content using HTML syntax.

```html
<a href="file:///$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\reports\latestReport\TestReport.html">Test Report</a>
```

Due to this is linking to a local file from the directory on the agent machine, if you receive and open the mail message on another machine, when you try to click the link from the message, you may get the warning that can't find the file path on the current machine.

[image]

If you want the send file can be opened from the received mail message, you can try the following methods:

1. Send the file as an attachment on the mail. You need to enable the option "**Add Attachment?**" and enter the absolute path of the file you want to attach.

   [image]
2. If the file you want to send is in your remote source repository, or you have published it to the service, as I mentioned above, you can send the Mail Body as HTML Body, and the path in the '**`a`**' tag should be the URL of the file in the repository or on the publish service.

   ```html
   <a href="https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/{proj_name}/_git/{repo_name}?path=/reports/latestReport/TestReport.html">Test Report</a>
   ```

   With this way, when you receive the mail message, you can click the link from the message to open and view the file on web browser.

Comment: Hi @Bright Ran-MSFT,
Thanks for your response.

My requirement is showing the HTML content in mail body. 
I am able to add the file as attachment and I am getting the mail with attachment. There is not problem with that.
I want to show the content of HTML in body of mail, which I achieved in Jenkins using ${FILE,path="abc\SummaryReport.html"}
I want something similar to this in azure, may be the syntax to mention file path in email body.

Comment: Hi @ram, I attempted a lot using the `Send email` task, but did not find any available way to insert the content of the HTML file in the mail body. I find another user has reported an issue ticket ([renevanosnabrugge/SendEmail-BuildTask#34](https://github.com/renevanosnabrugge/SendEmail-BuildTask/issues/34)) for the same question on the GitHub repository of this task. I recommend that you can follow this issue ticket and add you comments to it.

Comment: Great. Thank you. I appreciate it.